# Python - Can't connect to MS SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, database, database-connection, pyodbc

When I try to connect to MS SQL, I got this error:

```
> pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL
> Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified [xFFFFFFFF].  (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [HYT00]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0);
> [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or
> instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
> to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
> instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
> remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
> (-1)')
```

How can I resolve this error and finally connect to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it was solved by activating `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` in services. It turns out, it doesn't turn on automatically when the computer starts.

[image]

Comment: Just FYI. You can find an (simple) overview of all your SQL Server Instances / services in the SQL Server configuration manager  http://i.stack.imgur.com/NV6FM.png :)

Comment: Thanks! That's much more intuitive