# Why this error when getting data from MSSQL using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to retrieve data from MSSQL and this is the code I am using:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'xxxxxxxx\DEV'
database = 'SandBox'
username = 'zzzzzzz'
password = 'xxxxxxx'
driver = '{SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=4853;SERVER='+server+';PORT=4853;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from fieldscreenscheme ")
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print row
```

This is the error massage I got:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=43853;SERVER='+server+';PORT=43853;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

I installed the ODBC driver. Any recommendation how to solve this error?
I looked at these two but did not help me to solve this.
[Python - Can't connect to MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573669/python-cant-connect-to-ms-sql)
 [pyodbc + MySQL + Windows: Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288902/pyodbc-mysql-windows-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-speci)
Microsoft Documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-develop-python-simple.md

Comment: Still it does not any other recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1. Normally, one supplies **either** the `\INSTANCENAME` **or** the port number, not both.
2. ODBC connection strings for SQL Server do not use `PORT=`, they put the port number in the `SERVER=` parameter, e.g., `SERVER=xxxxxxxx,43853`. (Note that the instance name is omitted and the separator is a comma, not a colon.)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue whole day wasted and I tried all possible `ODBC Driver` for SQL Server here is the list, I just try one by one and it works for me

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2005 - 2014
Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2005 - 2016
Driver={ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2008 - 2016
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} for SQL Server 2008 - 2017
```

And these are some others we can use, somehow in my case the last one works :)

```
Driver={SQL Server} for SQL Server 2000
Driver={SQL Native Client} for SQL Server 2005
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} for SQL Server 2008
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0} for SQL Server 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

I've met same problem and fixed it changing connection string like below. 
Writing

```
driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
```

instead of

```
driver = '{SQL Server}'
```

Comment: which version of pyodbc ere you using? I used 4.0.26 and I had to do exactly opposite of your answer.

Comment: Version of pyodbc at execution environment could be 4.0.23, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Eswar can you see my answer below,